# UIGestureRecognizer and UISplitViewController

Tags: ipad, ios, uisplitviewcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

Ok so heres the setup: I'm using a splitViewController and in my master view controller there are two other view controller's views populating it. In one of those views theres two textfields and I want to make it so the keyboard will dismiss if they click anywhere outside those textfields. Ex. if they click anywhere in the detail view controller the keyboard should dismiss itself. Whats the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

set the split view as the textfield's delegate, then use the textFieldDidBeginEditing delegate method telling the split view to set a varible in the detail view that makes it send the textfield a resignFirstResponder on touchesBegan.